# How to Manage Wordpress theme header margin

Tags: wordpress, themes, chat

I have a [Indian Chat Room](http://www.livechat.org.in/india-chat-room/) Website
I am creating a custom theme, and elements behave as they should but when I place the `<?php wp_head() ?>` tag I get a top margin, at the top of my theme header.

When I remove the `<?php wp_head(); ?>` the margin goes away. I have been at this for a while any help would be great.

Comment: Please provide some code in order to help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the `<?php wp_head(); ?>` so I can take a look at your website.

Also try this in your CSS:

```
html{ margin-top:0px !important;}
```